# Do onMeasure in Android returns Size including padding and margin?

Tags: android, layout

I am working on a Custom Component and would like to know if onMeasure called on children would return width and height of the child including padding and margin of it?

Comment: You think or it is that?

Comment: If you could explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

The sizes passed in `onMeasure` includes the padding, but not the margin.

So, while implementing your `onMeasure` you should keep in mind:

- The padding.
- The minimum width and minimum height of our view (use `getSuggestedMinimumWidth()` and `getSuggestedMinimumHeight()` to get those values).
- The `widthMeasureSpec` and `heightMeasureSpec` which are the requirements passed to us by the parent.

Ref: [Custom View: mastering onMeasure | Lorenzo Quiroli](https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d)